Odoo 17 OWL Frontend: Leveraging External Libraries Compatible with Data Attributes and Event Listening
To integrate the Metronic library into my Odoo 17 OWL frontend portal effectively, I've loaded the JavaScript file from the assets in the manifest file, but it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.
Link to Theme Plugin
Since these plugins will be utilized across the entire application, I'm seeking guidance on how to leverage their event listening capabilities and data attribute operations within the OWL framework.
Any insights or alternative methods for seamless integration would be greatly appreciated, as I'm committed to ensuring consistent functionality throughout the portal.
Example of my usage:
<!-- Begin :: Compose Menu item   -->
<div data-kt-menu-trigger="click" class="menu-item menu-accordion">

    <!-- Begin :: Compose Menu link   -->
    <span class="menu-link">
        <span class="menu-icon">
            <i class="ki-duotone ki-feather">
                 <span class="path1"/>
                 <span class="path2"/>
            </i>
        </span>
        <span class="menu-title">Compose</span>
        <span class="menu-arrow"/>
    </span>
    <!-- End :: Compose Menu link  -->

    <!-- Begin :: Compose Menu sub  -->
    <div class="menu-sub menu-sub-accordion">

        <!-- Begin :: ION Menu item  -->
        <div class="menu-item">
            <!-- Begin :: Menu link -->
            <a class="menu-link" href="/eoffice/ion/compose">
                <span class="menu-bullet">
                     <span class="bullet bullet-dot"/>
                </span>
                <span class="menu-title">ION</span>
            </a>
            <!-- End :: Menu link   -->
         </div>
         <!-- End :: Menu item   -->

         <!-- Begin :: Compose Minute Sheet Menu item   -->
         <div class="menu-item">
         <!-- Begin :: Menu link   -->
             <a class="menu-link" href="/eoffice/minute_sheet/compose">
                 <span class="menu-bullet">
                     <span class="bullet bullet-dot"/>
                 </span>
                 <span class="menu-title">Minute Sheet</span>
             </a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End :: Compose Menu sub   -->

</div>
<!--  End :: Compose Menu item-->

I've loaded the JavaScript file from the assets in the manifest file, but it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.
Expecting: Menu sub accordion to be opened
